# Trigonometry and Logarithms

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms

> 1. If the equation $$\log_{10}(ax)\log_{10}(bx)+1=0$$ with $a>0$, $b>0$ constants has a solution $x>0$, it follows that $\frac ba \geq ans_{1}$ or $ans_{2}\geq \frac ba >ans_{3}$
> 2. If $$\cos\theta=\sqrt{\frac 12+\frac1{2\sqrt2}}$$ and $$\sin\theta=-\sqrt{\frac 12-\frac 1{2\sqrt2}}$$ with $0\leq \theta <2\pi$, it follows that $2\theta=ans_{4}\pi$
> 3. If $$y=\log_2\left(x+\sqrt{x_2+1}\right)$$ then $2^y-2^{-y}=ans_{5}x$
> 4. The function $$f(x)=\log_2(\log_3(\log_2(\log_3(\log_2x))))$$ has the interval $x>ans_{6}$ as its maximum domain on real numbers
>
> Find $ans_1,\cdots, ans_6$

I've no foundation in these but I'd appreciate if anyone could provide explanation for them. I've seen the answer but couldn't make anything from it.

EDIT: Sorry if this violated the rules here, apparently someone helped translate the whole thing into texts, I appreciate your help. Mods can you close the question? I'll do it right next time around :)

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange - please type out your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so that a) it isn't sideways and b) it is searchable on the site

Comment: For the last question, proceed from outside, and use the fact that $\log(1) 
= 0$

Comment: @lioness99a omg so embarassing, i'll change the question asap

Comment: For question $3$, use the fact that $$a^{\log_ab}=b$$ with $a=2$

Comment: Welcome. It looks like your question is on the brink of being closed. This is probably because it's been perceived as a do-my-homework-for-me task, which is not what this site is for. Dumping a handful of questions at once doesn't help. Generally, you should provide some sense of what you know and don't know about the problem. (You say you've seen the answers; include them for completeness.) This helps us tailor answers to you, and prevents us from telling you things you already know. Remember: You are asking a favor of the people here; try to make answering your question as easy as possible.

Comment: I removed the answer I gave and replaced it with hints.  You are absolutely correct to close the question or put it on hold as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** I removed the answer due to Blue's comment above.  If you already have it, fine, but refer to Blue's comment for asking future questions.

Hints for #2:

- Square $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$.
- Since we're looking for $2 \theta$, which trigonometric function applies?
- Your angles within the range you're looking for are in the first and fourth quadrants.